# Create Custom Identity Provider to be Used in Windows Azure Control Services

Tags: c#, azure, wif, identityserver3

I have begun to work with Microsoft Azure Access Control Services. I would like to create a custom identity provider which would authenticate against our back end CRM system. In the past, I had created a prototype Secure Token Service website which allowed me to do this. However, that was a few years ago. I found 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2012/11/02/azure-access-control-services-creating-a-custom-identity-provider/
which describes how to create a custom identity provider using WIF to be used within Azure but the site is dated from 2012. I had also looked at IdentityServer3 which I thought may be a replacement for WIF.

Do I use the WIF Secure Token Service approach? Is this obsolete? Is Identity Server the new way to accomplish the same thing?

Thanks.

Comment: [Azure Access Control Services is deprecated](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ad/2015/02/12/the-future-of-azure-acs-is-azure-active-directory/) and merging into Azure AD.

Comment: It can be difficult to find information about the latest version/approach or whether you are inadvertently looking into a deprecated solution which you pointed out here. I had originally looked into Azure AD but stumbled upon Azure Access Control Services. I will now go back and dig into Azure AD. Thanks!

Comment: Why would someone vote this down? I spent weeks looking and prototyping using Azure Access Control Services together with looking into Thinktecture and IdentityServer3 before realizing that I may be going in the wrong direction. I would have most likely continued to go in the wrong direction if I hadn't asked this question. The down vote states "This question does not show any research effort ..." - I spent weeks researching before posing this question. The question is very clear and has been extremely useful for me and I'm sure will be useful for others as well.

Comment: Iguad, I've looked for information regarding the equivalent functionality of Access Control Services in Azure AD and have not been able to find anything. Can you point me to any links/information? The link you provided is from February/2015 so I would think this functionality would now be available. The links I am finding all point to Azure ACS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all : Windows azure ACS will probably be discontinued (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ad/2015/02/12/the-future-of-azure-acs-is-azure-active-directory/).  We had a contact with Microsoft on this and they said it would be deprecated "two years from now" (not official).  This being said, to integrate your custom STS in windows azure ACS is "easy".  ACS just needs a pointer to your metadata document.  Normally if you have an STS that follows the WS-Federation standards it lives at https://yourSTS/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml.  If your meta data is correct, ACS will expose you STS as another identity provider (just like Google, Yahoo etc..).  It will do so by offering a "choice screen" that allows an end user to choose the identity provider of her choice.  You identity provider will then show up among them.  If the end user clicks the link for you identity provider the browser will be redirected to your STS (passive login).  If she logs in, a token will be issued to ACS.  ACS will them "transform" you security token and issue a new one to the final relying party.

Bon, answer is that you have to expose a meta data document and import it in acs https://yournamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/mgmt/web/IdentityProvider.

Answer (score 0):

ACS is being discontinued but who knows when.

ACS was originally introduced to provide social logins but has been used for many things e.g. changing token types from SAML 1.1 to SAML 2.0 and vice versa.

The "new" way to integrate social logins in Azure is Azure B2C but that is a completely different type of Azure tenant and has no SaaS integration.

Refer: [Azure B2C : Differences with Azure Active Directory (AAD)](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/05/azure-b2c-differences-with-azure-active.html) and [Azure B2C : Differences with Access Control Services (ACS)](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/05/azure-b2c-differences-with-access.html).

Identity Server 3 is open source, can do pretty much everything ACS can do plus you can add your own social logins and SAML 2.0 protocol and OpenID Connect / OAuth.

Another good option is Auth0 but that is commercial (and no I don't work for them :-) ).

Regarding WIF, it is still supported but no new features are being added. Rather migrate to OWIN.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. Well, a few years ago I had purchased the book - Programming Windows Identity Foundation by Vittorio Bertocci which I used to begin prototyping an SSO solution using the WS-Federation approach which uses a Security Token Service. That project was put on hold and I had not begun to look at this until recently. I purchased Vittorio's new book a few months ago - Modern Authentication with Azure Active Directory for Web Applications. I had only browsed the book but decided to take a it home with me this past weekend and read it thoroughly. The book describes the history of pre-claims authentication techniques to SAML to WS-Federation to OAuth to OpenID Connect. It has a great deal of code examples as well as detailed architectural information. This has cleared up the confusion of the different protocols and I now know in which direction to go.